# Vaadin 7/8 and embedded Jetty

Tags: vaadin, war, vaadin7, embedded-jetty, vaadin8

I would like to deploy a vaadin (version 7.2.5) web application using embedded jetty (eclipse luna builtin version).

Currently, my code looks like:

```
public class Launcher {
    private static int httpPort = 8080;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server();
        SocketConnector connector = new SocketConnector();
        connector.setMaxIdleTime(1000 * 60 * 10);
        connector.setSoLingerTime(-1);
        connector.setPort(httpPort);
        connector.setReuseAddress(false);
        QueuedThreadPool pool = new QueuedThreadPool();
        pool.setMinThreads(10);
        pool.setMaxThreads(100);
        server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });
        server.setThreadPool(pool);
        WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
        context.setServer(server);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.setWar("ReportWriter.war");
        context.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        server.setHandler(context);
        try
        {
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I've copied it from a [vaadin forum thread](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3062995). The server seems to start and the WAR actually gets extracted.

Pointing my browser to `http://localhost:8080/`, instead of starting my vaadin (version 7.2.5) app, all what I see is:

[image: localhost:8080]

Just in case it might be important: My directory tree of the WAR project in eclipse:

```
ReportWriter
|   .classpath
|   .project
|   ivy.xml
|   ivysettings.xml
|   
+---.settings
|       (...)
|       
+---build
|   \---classes
|       +---(...)
|       \---META-INF
|               persistence.xml
|               
+---src
|   +---(...)
|   \---META-INF
|           persistence.xml
|           
\---WebContent
    |   dropDDL.sql
    |   init.sql
    |   reportwriter.xml
    |   
    +---META-INF
    |       MANIFEST.MF
    |       
    +---VAADIN
    \---WEB-INF
        \---lib
                BorderLayout-0.5.jar
                confirmdialog-2.0.4.jar
                dawn-2.jar
                derby.jar
                derbynet.jar
                derbyrun.jar
                derbytools.jar
                messagebox-2.0.6.jar
                refresher-1.2.1.7.jar
                vaadin-jpacontainer-3.1.1-javadoc.jar
                vaadin-jpacontainer-3.1.1-sources.jar
                vaadin-jpacontainer-3.1.1.jar
                wizards-for-vaadin-1.0.1.jar
```

And the one of my RWRunner (launcher) project:

```
RWRunner
|   .classpath
|   .project
|   ivy.xml
|   ivysettings.xml
|   ReportWriter.war  <-- The war file generated from the project above
|   test.txt
|   web.xml
|   
+---.settings
|       .jsdtscope
|       com.vaadin.integration.eclipse.prefs
|       org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
|       org.eclipse.wst.common.component
|       org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
|       org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container
|       org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.name
|       
+---build
|   \---classes
|       \---ch
|           \---darkspot
|               \---rwrunner
|                       Launcher.class
|                       
\---src
    \---ch
        \---darkspot
            \---rwrunner
                    Launcher.java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are somehow missing the servlet configuration needed to map the /* to the Vaadin web application. There seems to be web.xml in place that should take care of that, but check that the content is referring to right Servlet/UI classes and URI.

Alternatively to mapping in web.xml you can have a `@WebServlet` annotated servlet in your UI class (when using JSR 315):

```
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyDemoUI.class)
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
```

Furthermore, the WAR structure above looks suspicious (although the directory listing in browser screenshot looks ok). Make sure the classes are under `/WEB-INF/classes/`, in order to be visible for the servlet container. And also that web.xml under /WEB-INF.

Comment: you were right. The classes weren't in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder. Now I've moved them, but it doesn't seem to find the class I'm mentioning in my `web.xml`. Maybe something's wrong with the classpath?